# Matching values from multiple columns to populate another

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to compare column A against column B. When there is a match, I'd Like to populate a resulting column (column D) with data from column C.

I have a partial parts list (column A) that I am comparing against a complete parts list (column B). When a match occurs, I'd like to extract the corresponding data from complete parts list, nomenclature (column C) and place it next to the matching part number in column A.

BEFORE

```
Column A         Column B                  Column C           Column D
Part Number      Description               Part Number        Description
123456           Bolt                      123456
```

AFTER

```
Column A         Column B                  Column C           Column D
Part Number      Description               Part Number        Description
123456           Bolt                      123456             Bolt
```

Comment: Your description and the example don't match... could you clarify and maybe include some more rows in your example?

Comment: Seems like a good time to use `Index` and `Match` functions. Please do clarify your question.

Comment: Also, when you revise, please give your question a meaningful title. Currently, you're just telling people what version of Excel/MS you are using, which is not descriptive at all. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I'll bite, assuming you've simply mis-labeled your examples, what you want to do can be done easily enough using formulas.

In cell D2, put the formula:

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,FALSE))`

[image]

**How it works:** The `Match` function returns the relative row number in column A, and the `Index` function uses that row # to return the value in corresponding row in column B.  Likewise, you could do:

`=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)`